# How can I change the option of a select with jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, select, buddypress

I am using the BuddyPress plugin to create a multi-select option in user the profile. Unfortunately, before people click this select, the display text is '----'. I want to use jquery to change the display text from '----' to something like 'Please select'.  How can I do that in jQuery?

```html
<select id="field_221" name="field_221" aria-required="true">
    <option value="">----</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option> value="14">14</option>
    <option> value="15">15</option>
</select>
```

Comment: We need some code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by iterating through the select options and replacing any that are equal to '----'.

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function () { // Executes on DOM ready
    $("#field_221 > option").each(function () {
        if (this.text === '----') {
            this.text = 'Please select';
        }
    });
});
```

**Demo**:  http://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/8r3d9r9c/

Also, you have an extra `>` in the last two options. Change `<option> value...` to `<option value...`.